# Add banner image on both top and bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I know how to put an banner image on the top of the page, but how do I put one on the bottom as well.  My code for the banner on top is:

```
<img src="Pics/images4.jpg" alt="wave lines" id="image">

#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
}
```

I do not want the image to be fixed or centered, but to stretch across from left to right.  So that when someone reaches the bottom of the page, they will see the same image there as was on the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use background image.

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvebya)**

```css
html {
  background: url("//dummyimage.com/4000x200") center top / auto 100px no-repeat, url("//dummyimage.com/4000x200") center bottom / auto 100px no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. `margin-top: auto` will push a flex item to the bottom of the container in this case.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1350x150">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `background-attachment:fixed`, and add a transparent section to the top and bottom of your page.

```
<div class="padded">
    <h2>This is a Title</h2>
</div>

#image { 
    background-attachment:fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
}

.padded {
    padding:100px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

This will create the window effect, so the image won't scroll when the page does, but will allow the same image to be seen at the top and bottom of the page.